# Best practice to mount directory in /home to directory in /media?

Tags: debian, symlink, fstab

I have 4 drives on my home server. 3 external drives mounted in fstab to three individual directories in /media. The fourth drive contains a headless debian os install. I want to mount a directory in my home folder on the os drive to a directory in /media, to get easier access to the drives storage space. Am I looking into setting it up in fstab, or use a symlink. What is the best approach to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ln -s /home /media/volume`

Much safer option security-wise. Won't accidentally overwrite or delete important system files, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise leaving the mount in its default location and using a cross drive sym / soft link. Only change mount points from defaults if that's the only place you'll want to access the drive.